# jquery fade effect not working in FF

Tags: jquery, firefox, fade, fadeout

This piece of code fades the div fine in IE.  In Firefox 3.0.8, the fade time goes by and the div disappears instantly.  I can't find anyone mentioning this problem.

```
   $(function() {
            $("#show").click(function() {
                $("#show").fadeOut('slow');
            });
        });


<div id="show">this is where to show it</div>
```

Comment: I've actually simplifies the problem.  I can't get anything to fadeOut in Firefox 3.0.8 at all.  I've not seen anything about this problem when searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help.

I found the problem.  My example wasn't complete.  I had also included `jquery-vsdoc.js` for jQuery VS intellisense.  Taking this out made it work.

I used this trick for future readers

```
<%if (false) { %>
<script src="common/jquery-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% } %>
```

Wierd.

Answer (score 7):

I've been banging my head against this problem all morning and finally found my problem...
the header to "Scripts/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js"

```
/*
 * This file has been commented to support Visual Studio Intellisense.
 * You should not use this file at runtime inside the browser--it is only
 * intended to be used only for design-time IntelliSense.  Please use the
 * standard jQuery library for all production use.
 *
 * Comment version: 1.3.2a
 */
```

when they say **"You should not use this file at runtime inside the browser"** they certainly do mean it...

so make sure you are using the non -vsdoc versions of jquery and jquery-min

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me on Firefox 3.0.8 and Windows XP.

[Here is the sample page I tested it on.](http://jsbin.com/ewica)

Answer (score 1):

Working for me as well

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
            $("#show").click(function() {
                $("#show").fadeOut('slow');
            });
        });
</script>
   <div id="show">this is where to show it</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was banging my head around this for a long time.  My code didn't even have anything to do with any jquery-vsdoc.js.

Solution: Just close the browser, reopen it, load the page again.

Not sure why the heck it wasn't working.

Don't let yourself go crazy like I did!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I tried to do the animation in CSS first and left this in which caused problems doing it in jQuery.

```
    transition:.5s linear;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put event.preventDefault() there in order to make it work.

```
$(function() {
     $("#show").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#show").fadeOut('slow');
     });
 });


<div id="show">this is where to show it</div>
```